# File handling: Only last item is modified from file in c and file not removed when already given command to be removed

Tags: c, file-handling

**(If this problem has been asked previously, please do tell. I can't figure out what the exact problem is, therefore, I decided to post this question)**

**(I have also tried an alternate method where the content of file(inventory) is temporarily stored in memory, then modified before putting it back to the file, but I would like to know why the** **method below does not work as intended)**

I am currently trying to make a cashier program in c. I encountered two problems when trying to decrease the stock items after purchase.

Problem#1 = only last item selected during transaction is successfully decreased from inventory

Problem#2 = the part where it is supposed to remove and rename file doesn't work

This is the part of the code that I think both of the problems reside on:

```
//modifying item stock after bought
    for (int j = 0; j < item_counter; j++) {
        char buffer_char[10001];
        int buffer_int[2];
        int  line = 0;
        //printf("--=test num %d %d\n", j, customer.pitem[j].item_id);

        //for getting item price and stock from file
        FILE *flist, *fstock, *tlist, *tstock;
        flist = fopen("item_list.txt", "r");
        fstock = fopen("item_stock.txt", "r");

        //creating or resetting the temporary file
        tlist = fopen("temp_list.txt", "w");
        tstock = fopen("temp_stock.txt", "w");

        while(fgets(buffer_char, 10000, flist) != NULL) {
            if(customer.pitem[j].item_id != (line + 1)){
                //getting item name price and stock from file current line
                buffer_char[strlen(buffer_char) - 1] = '\0';
                fscanf(fstock, "%d %d", &buffer_int[0], &buffer_int[1]);

                //printf("fail\n");
                fprintf(tlist, "%s\n", buffer_char);
                fprintf(tstock, "%d %d\n", buffer_int[0], buffer_int[1]);
            }

            else if(customer.pitem[j].item_id == (line + 1)) {
                //getting item name price and stock from file current line
                buffer_char[strlen(buffer_char) - 1] = '\0';
                fscanf(fstock, "%d %d", &buffer_int[0], &buffer_int[1]);

                //printf("success\n");
                buffer_int[1] = buffer_int[1] - customer.pitem[j].item_quantity;
                fprintf(tlist, "%s\n", buffer_char);
                fprintf(tstock, "%d %d\n", buffer_int[0], buffer_int[1]);
            }

            line++;
        }

        //closing all files
        fclose(flist);
        fclose(fstock);
        fclose(tlist);
        fclose(tstock);
        
        //removing the original file
        remove("item_list.txt");
        remove("item_stock.txt");

        //renaming the temporary file
        rename("temp_list.txt", "item_list.txt");
        rename("temp_stock.txt", "item_stock.txt");
    }
```

This is the content of **item_list.txt** before any purchase are made:

```
Susu Kental Manis
Chitatos
Taros
Koka Kola
Bang bang
```

This is the content of **item_stock.txt** before any purchase are made (the numbers on the left are prices, while the ones on the right are quantities in inventory):

```
13000 20
12000 20
7000 20
5000 20
4000 20
```

This is the entire code for context:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

//for displaying all items without yes or no
void display_inventory_woyn() {
    FILE *fh_input_list, *fh_input_stock;
    fh_input_list = fopen("item_list.txt", "r+");
    fh_input_stock = fopen("item_stock.txt", "r+");

    char buffer_char[10001];
    int buffer_int[2];
    int line = 0;

    //getting item names from file
    while (fgets(buffer_char, 10000, fh_input_list) != NULL) {
        //fgets(buffer_char, 10000, fh_input_list);
        buffer_char[strlen(buffer_char) - 1] = '\0';
        printf("%d. %s   ", (line + 1), buffer_char);

        //getting item price and stock from file
        fscanf(fh_input_stock, "%d %d", &buffer_int[0], &buffer_int[1]);
        printf("Rp.%d   Qty.%d\n", buffer_int[0], buffer_int[1]);

        //incrementing line customer_counter
        line++;
    }
        

    fclose(fh_input_list);
    fclose(fh_input_stock);
}

int get_date() {
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    struct tm *cur_time = localtime(&now);
    return("%d", cur_time->tm_mday);
}
int get_month() {
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    struct tm *cur_time = localtime(&now);
    return("%d", cur_time->tm_mon + 1);
}
int get_year() {
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    struct tm *cur_time = localtime(&now);
    return("%d", cur_time->tm_year + 1900);
}
int get_hour() {
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    struct tm *cur_time = localtime(&now);
    return("%d", cur_time->tm_hour);
}
int get_minute() {
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    struct tm *cur_time = localtime(&now);
    return("%d", cur_time->tm_min);
}

typedef struct {
    char month_name[13][20];
}months;

months month_list = {
        "January", 
        "February", 
        "March", 
        "April", 
        "May", 
        "June", 
        "July", 
        "August", 
        "September", 
        "October", 
        "November", 
        "December"
};

typedef struct {
    int date;
    int month;
    int year;

    int hour;
    int minute;
}full_date;

typedef struct {
    char item_name[10001];
    int item_id;
    int item_price;
    int item_quantity;
}item_properties;

typedef struct {
    full_date fdate;
    char customer_name[51];
    item_properties pitem[101];
    
    int total_price;
    int total_quantity;
    int payment;
} order;

order customer;

void cashier_menu() {
    printf ("-------------\n");
    printf (" > CASHIER < \n");
    printf ("-------------\n");
    //getting current date and time
    customer.fdate.date = get_date();
    customer.fdate.month = get_month();
    customer.fdate.year = get_year();
    customer.fdate.hour = get_hour();
    customer.fdate.minute = get_minute();
    //displaying current date and time
    printf("Date: %d %s %d || %d:%d\n", customer.fdate.date, month_list.month_name[customer.fdate.month - 1], customer.fdate.year, customer.fdate.hour, customer.fdate.minute);
    printf ("-------------\n");

    //for getting customer name
    printf("Enter customer name: ");
    fgets(customer.customer_name, 50, stdin);
    //removing \n cased by fgets
    customer.customer_name[strlen(customer.customer_name) - 1] = '\0';
    printf ("-------------\n");

    //display item list
    display_inventory_woyn();
    printf ("-------------\n");

    int item_counter = 0;
    while(true){
        //for getting item price and stock from file
        FILE *flist, *fstock;
        flist = fopen("item_list.txt", "r");
        fstock = fopen("item_stock.txt", "r");

        //asking for item id to buy
        int temp_id = 0;
        printf("Enter item id to buy (enter 0 to finish purchase): ");
        scanf("%d", &temp_id);

        //to consume the \n at the end of scanf
        while ((getchar()) != '\n');

        bool item_existance = false;
        char buffer_char[10001];
        int buffer_int[2];

        //for checknig exit
        if(temp_id <= 0){
            break;
        }

        //checking for item existance
        else {
            int line = 0;
            while (fgets(buffer_char, 10000, flist) != NULL) {
                //getting item name price and stock from file current line
                buffer_char[strlen(buffer_char) - 1] = '\0';

                //when item is found
                if (temp_id == (line + 1)) {
                    //fetching item id to struct
                    customer.pitem[item_counter].item_id = temp_id;
                    //get item price and stock from file
                    fscanf(fstock, "%d %d", &buffer_int[0], &buffer_int[1]);
                    //fetching item name to struct
                    strcpy(customer.pitem[item_counter].item_name, buffer_char);
                    //fetching item price to struct
                    customer.pitem[item_counter].item_price = buffer_int[0];
                    //confirming item existance
                    item_existance = true;

                    break;
                }
                //incrementing line
                line++;
            }

        }

        if(item_existance == true) {
            while(true){
                //asking for how many items to buy
                printf("Enter item quantity: ");
                scanf("%d", &customer.pitem[item_counter].item_quantity);

                //if item quantity is 0
                if(customer.pitem[item_counter].item_quantity == 0 || customer.pitem[item_counter].item_quantity < 0){
                    printf("Please enter an amount greater than 0!\n");
                }

                //if requeested quantity is less than or equal to stock
                else if(customer.pitem[item_counter].item_quantity <= buffer_int[1]){
                    printf("%d Item '%s' added to cart!\n", customer.pitem[item_counter].item_quantity, buffer_char);
                    //adding quantity to total quantity
                    customer.total_quantity += customer.pitem[item_counter].item_quantity;
                    //adding price to total price
                    customer.total_price += (customer.pitem[item_counter].item_quantity * buffer_int[0]);
                    break;
                }

                //if requested quantity is grater than stock
                else{
                    printf("Quantity requested: %d, is more than availability: %d\n", customer.pitem[item_counter].item_quantity, buffer_int[1]);
                }
            }

            //incrementing item counter
            item_counter++;
            printf("\n");
        }

        else {
        printf("Item index %d not found!\n", temp_id);
        }
        
        fclose(flist);
        fclose(fstock);
        
    }

    //displaying total price
    printf ("\n-------------\n");
    printf("Your total price for %d item is: Rp.%d\n", customer.total_quantity, customer.total_price);

    //asking for payment
    while(true){
        printf("Enter payment: Rp.");
        scanf("%d", &customer.payment);
        //to consume the \n at the end of scanf
        while ((getchar()) != '\n');

        if (customer.payment >= customer.total_price){
            printf("Change: Rp.%d\n", customer.payment - customer.total_price);
            printf ("-------------\n");
            break;
        }
        else{
            printf("Payment is less than total price!\n");
        }
    }

    //printf("+++++item types %d\n", item_counter);


//!function for modifiying files---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    //modifying item stock after bought
    for (int j = 0; j < item_counter; j++) {
        char buffer_char[10001];
        int buffer_int[2];
        int  line = 0;
        //printf("--=test num %d %d\n", j, customer.pitem[j].item_id);

        //for getting item price and stock from file
        FILE *flist, *fstock, *tlist, *tstock;
        flist = fopen("item_list.txt", "r");
        fstock = fopen("item_stock.txt", "r");

        //creating or resetting the temporary file
        tlist = fopen("temp_list.txt", "w");
        tstock = fopen("temp_stock.txt", "w");

        while(fgets(buffer_char, 10000, flist) != NULL) {
            if(customer.pitem[j].item_id != (line + 1)){
                //getting item name price and stock from file current line
                buffer_char[strlen(buffer_char) - 1] = '\0';
                fscanf(fstock, "%d %d", &buffer_int[0], &buffer_int[1]);

                //printf("fail\n");
                fprintf(tlist, "%s\n", buffer_char);
                fprintf(tstock, "%d %d\n", buffer_int[0], buffer_int[1]);
            }

            else if(customer.pitem[j].item_id == (line + 1)) {
                //getting item name price and stock from file current line
                buffer_char[strlen(buffer_char) - 1] = '\0';
                fscanf(fstock, "%d %d", &buffer_int[0], &buffer_int[1]);

                //printf("success\n");
                buffer_int[1] = buffer_int[1] - customer.pitem[j].item_quantity;
                fprintf(tlist, "%s\n", buffer_char);
                fprintf(tstock, "%d %d\n", buffer_int[0], buffer_int[1]);
            }

            line++;
        }

        //closing all files
        fclose(flist);
        fclose(fstock);
        fclose(tlist);
        fclose(tstock);
        
        //removing the original file
        remove("item_list.txt");
        remove("item_stock.txt");
        //renaming the temporary file
        rename("temp_list.txt", "item_list.txt");
        rename("temp_stock.txt", "item_stock.txt");
    }

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    //printing history to console
    char invoice_ask;
    printf("\n");
    printf("Do you want to print the invoice? (y/n): ");
    scanf("%c", &invoice_ask);
    //checking for invoice print
    if (invoice_ask == 'y'){
        //clear console
        system("cls");

        printf("------------------------\n");
        printf(" >> CUSTOMER INVOICE << \n");
        printf("------------------------\n");

        printf("Customer name: %s\n", customer.customer_name);
        printf("Transaction Date: %d %s %d || %d:%d\n", customer.fdate.date, month_list.month_name[customer.fdate.month - 1], customer.fdate.year, customer.fdate.hour, customer.fdate.minute);
        printf("Items Bought:\n");
        printf ("-------------\n");
        //printing purchsed items
        for(int i = 0; i < item_counter; i++){
            printf("%d. %s || Rp.%d || %d\n", (i + 1), customer.pitem[i].item_name, customer.pitem[i].item_price, customer.pitem[i].item_quantity);
        }
        printf ("-------------\n");

        printf("Total quantity: %d\n", customer.total_quantity);
        printf("Total price: Rp.%d\n", customer.total_price);
        printf("Payment: Rp.%d\n", customer.payment);
        printf("Change: Rp.%d\n", customer.payment - customer.total_price);
        printf ("-------------\n");
        printf("Thank you for shopping with us!\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Thank you for shopping with us!\n");
    }
    //back to main menu
    printf("going back to menu...");
    //main_menu();
}


//dirver code
int main() {
    cashier_menu();
    return 0;
}
```

Here are some input output examples and how the changes are reflected in **temp_stock.txt**:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

As seen from 2 set of examples above, only the last added/purchased item is the only one that was successfully modified from the inventory when being copied to temp_stock.txt.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you step through line by line in your debugger? What did yo see?

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting the file pointer with the fseek() function, this would tell the program to begin reading from the beginning of a new file, without it it would either just start reading from wherever, or it would pick up at the position of the last file